# Finding pythagorian triplets, with sum 1000, no error but doesnt runs

Tags: c++, system-calls

Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    float c, d;
    for(int a = 1; a < 1000; ++a) {
        for(int b = 1; b < 1000; ++b) {
            c = (a*a) + (b*b);
            c = sqrt(c);
            d = a + b + c;
            if(d==1000) {
                std::cout << a << "," << b << "," << c << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Cannot run it on my system **Dev-C++ 4.9.9.0**.

But when tried it in an online compiler and it gave the output but with the following output:

```
200,375,425
375,200,425

Disallowed system call: SYS_fork
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine that the online compiler disallows calling

```
system("pause");
```

since that creates a new process. Try removing that line and see if it runs better!

Another way of pausing at the end of the program would be to include iostream at the top, and then wait for input at the end, before returning:

```
//At the top
#include <iostream>

// Before return 0;
std::cin.get();
```

Comment: thankx for that... But any idea why it doesnt runs on my system?? iam using dev cpp 4.9.9.0. 2.0Ghz core2duo ,3gig ram...

Comment: You're welcome. Could you specify exactly what happens when you try to run the program? Compiler error?

Comment: No errors only the dos window or the output window ( whatever it is called) doesnt comes up. I checked the compiler section and it says zero errors. but lately i guess my compiler has become slow, like the output windows for simple program as hello world even takes 4 sec to come up.Earlier it used to come up instantly.i have tried reinstalling but its the same.

Comment: It's really hard to say. If you've got an IDE like Visual C++ 2010 Express you could debug and step through your program, or you could add some debug text output along the way. You could also try another compiler!